# "Tile error: matrixSolve cannot solve underdetermined system" in Google Earth Engine

Tags: libgee

run SG filter https://code.earthengine.google.com/7ba9ccf18a4da7887c6f060a8e7d769c on my earth engine then I got the error "sg: Tile error: matrixSolve cannot solve underdetermined system."  but the image can be successfully added; when I change the input of SG to my produced global imagecollection, nothing can be shown just the mentioned error. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of the null value in the image (e.g., the part over the sea), just use unmask to turn null value to zero

```
var modis_res = Mod_col.filterDate(start_date, end_date).filterBounds(aoi).map(function(img) {
    img = img.select(['NDVI', 'EVI']).set('date', dstamp).unmask()
    return img
})
```